# How do clear / zero a NSMutableString that is used for receiving chars via the serial port?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, serial-port, arduino

I have an NSMutableString that I would like to clear out after I receive a series of chars from an Arduino.  The method that receives the chars looks like the following,

```
# pragma mark - JailbrokenSerialDelegate
- (void) JailbrokenSerialReceived:(char)ch {

    //NSLog(@"Received %c", ch);
    [text appendFormat:@"%c", ch];
    //[text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%c",ch];
    NSLog(@"Received %@",text);

    if ([text isEqual: @"{valve_open}"]) {
        _lblValveState.text = @"Valve Opened.";
    }

    if ([text isEqual: @"{valve_close}"]) {
        _lblValveState.text =@"Valve Closed.";
    }

}
```

Basically, this method runs through everytime a char is sent, and appends the new char to the previously collected one, and then constructs a NSMutableString "text" from the chars.  I can't set the string to nil in this method because it will zero out the string after one char is received, so I need a way to collect all the chars that are sent from the Arduino, and after all the chars are sent, I need to then set the string "text" to nil.  The reason for this is if I tap the button "openValve" and open the valve the Arduino sends the chars "{valve_open}" to the iPhone one at a time, and the eventually the "text" string condition will be met.  Now I when I press the close valve button the string "text" will still contain the chars from the open valve state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[text setString:@""];
```

should remove the characters from the string.  Note that using a NSString for this may not necessarily be a good thing, as you're not taking into account that NSStrings can store multibyte data.  It's probably good enough for what you're doing but You may be better off storing the arduino output into an NSData object, using  NSUTF8Encoding (or whatever the Arduino is sending you), then converting it to strings as needed.  You probably want to use [text isEqualToString:@"{valve_close}"] if you're going to stay with NSStrings.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and I am using a NSMutableString not an NSString, I think I have it figured out now too, for some reason typing out the question helped clear the problem for me, and I believe I have a solution.

Comment: Our solutions match, but you should still consider for the future that NSString stores Unicode characters, and that you may be getting 8 bit ASCII characters from the Arduino.

Comment: It would have been nice if you would have stated where the above line of code goes in the code block posted above, but no worries, I figured it out, and I'll give you the credit for the answer :)  ...merry christmas.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the following code,

```
# pragma mark - JailbrokenSerialDelegate
- (void) JailbrokenSerialReceived:(char)ch {

    //NSLog(@"Received %c", ch);
    [text appendFormat:@"%c", ch];
    //[text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%c",ch];
    NSLog(@"Received %@",text);

    if ([text isEqual: @"{valve_open}"]) {
        _lblValveState.text = @"Valve Opened.";
        [text setString:@""];
    }

    if ([text isEqual: @"{valve_close}"]) {
        _lblValveState.text =@"Valve Closed.";
        [text setString:@""];
    }

}
```